# How can I bulk upsert entities with typeorm?

Tags: mysql, sql, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to figure out how to make upsert SQL working with typeorm entities (not using querybuilder!!)

```
const items = Items[] //Items are the entity which extends BaseEntity
await this.repository.save(items)
```

this just works fine, but when I look at the console then it makes this SQL:

```
UPDATE Database.items SET created_at=(something) WHERE id=(something)
UPDATE Database.items SET created_at=(something) WHERE id=(something)
UPDATE Database.items SET created_at=(something) WHERE id=(something)
...
```

Although it is tied up by START TRANSACTION and COMMIT, I want to do the same thing but not with transaction.

I want something like this:

```
UPDATE Database.items SET created_at=(something) WHERE id IN (somethings)
```

How do I make this with only using typeorm's AbstractRepository?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this via the TypeOrm repositories. I didn't test the code in the IDE but I'm 100% sure this approach works.

```
const items = Items[] //Items are the entity which extends BaseEntity
const itemIds = items.map(item => item.id);
await this.repository.update({id: In(itemIds)}, {createdAt: "something"})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer the docs links [updatequery](https://typeorm.io/#/update-query-builder) and [wheredocs](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/adding-where-expression). This should resolve your issue.

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";
const itemIds = [1,2,3];

await getConnection()
.createQueryBuilder()
.update(Item)
.set({ created_at: "something" })
.where("items.id IN (:...ids)", { ids: itemIds })
.execute();
```

Comment: My aim is to not use queryBuilder. How can I do the same thing with repository?